# Capturing http requests from firefox?

Tags: firefox, fiddler

I have both Fiddler and Fiddler hook addon for firefox. While attempting to track down an error, I found that fiddler will not capture http requests in firefox but will capture them in Chrome. I tried disabling fiddler hook to see if somehow that caused a conflict but it didn't help. Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it?

(Crosposted from superuser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox takes a bit more setup.  Read here: http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/04/01/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler